# Connect to Office 365 through ADFS

Tags: c#, outlook, adfs2.0, office365, adfs

I'm what might be considered a total Rookie,
and I'm currently set up for a Task at work to connect an Outlook Addin to Office 365 through ADFS,
so i only use the Username (instead User and Password) while connecting to a specific Office 365 URL

My question to people who are experienced in this is really simple:
Is this doable, 
(if so, do you have any insights you could share)

Thnx in Advance, your help is really Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Well, it *should* be possible; but I'll warn you that it will not be simple. From personal experience building a product that integrates with Office365 and AD (and ADFS), you will likely spend a lot of time troubleshooting.

It will help if you if you get a better understanding of how claims identity works (e.g. security tokens, SAML, WS-Federation, WS-Trust). It's quite a bit to digest and be prepared for a rather big time investment.

It would help of you expanded on:

- What does the addin do? What does it connect to in O365?
- What technology is it built on?
- Which version of Office?